# Success constraint after For Loop container triggers before loop completes

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a For Loop inside another For Loop. The inner one seems to complete while it is still running. The "Log end history" script shows a green tick mark while items inside the inner loop continue to flash the spinner.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to make it behave?

Comment: More info please... :)

Comment: As I'm not quite sure what would be relevant in this case and, on the other hand, I don't want to clog up the question with my entire package, I'll take any suggestions on what other information should be provided and will follow reasonable ones. :)

Comment: For starters "The inner one seems to complete while it is still running.". Clarify "it" do you mean the outer loop shows it as running  and the inner step shows a tick mark?

Comment: Good point. The "Log end history" script shows a green tick mark while items inside the inner loop continue to flash the spinner.

Comment: Here's one more point... VS just crashed with an out of memory error... and my dev box has 128 GB RAM... :O  I then broght VS back up and ran the package again - no more premature success. Go figure.

Comment: I have had my share of issues with debugging in VS.. usually a restart of the application or reload fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has this issue, mine was solved by restarting Visual Studio.